# FindBy property in TYPO3 Extbase MVC is not working

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm unable to run the `FindBy` magic function property in Extbase MVC

```
    $title=array(0 =>'Books Day');

    $each_event=$this->eventRepository->findByTitle($title);
```

`$each_event` is returning an object of type `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult` .

How do I make this work?

I also tried passing in a string to `findByTitle` and `findByOne`. Both don;t work! :(

I'm using TYPO3 6.1 and extension builder.

Comment: Is the problem still exists?

Answer (score 3):

The last part of those magic functions always needs to be a field in the database. So "title" must be in your model. You might have a field "one" for your object, but I guess you meant findOneByTitle?

The object type QueryResult is correct. You can turn it into an array for debugging purpose for example:

```
$foo = $query->execute()->toArray();
```

By the way: check wether your eventRepository is null or not and you could try this to see if it works at all:

```
$result = $this->myRepository->findAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$each_event=$this->eventRepository->findByTitle($title)->toArray();
```

Reference to the [QueryResult](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/_query_result_8php_source.html).

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html), it returns a `QueryResultInterface|array`.

As a consequence you have to loop over the result like this:

```
foreach($each_event as $single_event) {
    $single_event->getProperty();
}
```

If you are sure that it returns only one single value you could also access it by the index `0`:

```
$each_event[0]->getProperty();
```